# JS gets reset after update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a JS function which shows and hides drop down lists and is called when that drop down list changes. However, I am also using update panels for something else, and every time I select something, the JS gets reset and the extra drop down lists  that I want to keep showing get reset i.e. hidden again (although it doesn't reset the value which is good).

The extra drop down lists are hidden by default. When the user selects 2 for example, it will show 2 drop down lists. How can I make it so the drop down lists aren't hidden again after the update panel has refreshed.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Preference CSS -->
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Preference.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Loading Page
    });


    function changeNumOfRooms(ddl) {
        if (ddl.value == "1") {
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL1.ClientID %>").style.display = "";//changes the number of room number fields
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL2.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL3.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
            }

            if (ddl.value == "2") {
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL1.ClientID %>").style.display = "";//changes the number of room number fields
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL2.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL3.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
            }

            if (ddl.value == "3") {
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL1.ClientID %>").style.display = "";//changes the number of room number fields
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL2.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
                document.getElementById("<%=roomNumDDL3.ClientID %>").style.display = "";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

```
<%-- Body Content --%>
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateModule" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="modCodeDDL" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="modTitleDDL" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <a href="#" title="Select the module code (Mandatory Field)">Module Code*</a>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="modCodeDDL" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="modCodeToTitle" AutoPostBack="True" />
        <a href="#" title="The name of the module e.g. 'Team Projects'. Mandatory Field.">Module Title*</a>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="modTitleDDL" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="modTitleToCode" AutoPostBack="True" Style="width: 250px;" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdateBuilding" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="buildingDDL" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="parkDDL" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <a href="#" title="Choose the park that you would like. Mandatory Field.">Park*</a><!-- PARK -->
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="parkDDL" Style="width: 150px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="parkToBuilding" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="ALL"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Central" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="West" Value="W"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="East" Value="E"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <a href="#" title="Choose the building that you would like">Building</a><!-- BUILDING -->
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" ID="buildingDDL" runat="server" style="width:300px;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="buildingToRoom"></asp:DropDownList>

    <a href="#" title="Do you require a particular room? If so select here">Room Number</a><!-- ROOM NUMBER -->
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="roomNumDDL1" title="For room 1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="roomNumDDL2" title="For room 2" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList class="form-control" ID="roomNumDDL3" title="For room 3" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<a href="#" title="Enter the number of rooms required for this lecture e.g. 1,2,...">Number of rooms*</a><!-- NUMBER OF ROOMS -->
<asp:DropDownList ID="numOfRoomsDDL" runat="server" onchange="changeNumOfRooms(this)">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

All JS content is called above of the ASP.NET.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in and it didn't work. But I think this is because the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager bit isn't highlighting blue. I might not have the right libraries...

Answer (score 1):

Your DropDownList visibility changes function must be call in `$(document).ready` as well as _endRequest event also. Check my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var numOfRoomsDDL = document.getElementById("<%= numOfRoomsDDL.ClientID%>");
     changeNumOfRooms(numOfRoomsDDL);
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {
              var numOfRoomsDDL = document.getElementById("<%= numOfRoomsDDL.ClientID%>");
     changeNumOfRooms(numOfRoomsDDL);
});
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code in and it didn't work. But I think this is because the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager bit isn't highlighting blue. I might not have the right libraries...

Comment: It is Javascript code. It's not a c# code so it should not be blue.